# Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle, csv

I'm trying to read in data from a csv file into a table from a database that I created. I've done it so far for 3 tables so the code for the fourth one should be relatively the same, but I keep receiving the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
>     at Verbindung.main(Verbindung.java:136)

this should be a pretty simple problem to fix but I can't see where I'm going wrong as the index and number of variables in my array appear to match up fine.

Here is my code

```
  // Parsing CSV file Facebookapp 
           try {
                Scanner inputStream3 = new Scanner(file3);
                //inputStream.useDelimiter("[;/n]");
                while(inputStream3.hasNext()) {
                    String data3 = inputStream3.next();
                    System.out.println(data3);
                    String[] values3 = data3.split(";");    
                    System.out.println(data3);
                    //if(values.toString().contains(";;;")) break;
                    int PRODNUM = Integer.parseInt(values3[0]);
                    double V_ERSION = Double.parseDouble(values3[1]);
                    String PHONE_ASSOC = values3[2];
                    int accountNUM = Integer.parseInt(values3[3]);
                    //creating the object FBapp with the relevant parameters
                    FBapp fbapp = new FBapp(PRODNUM, V_ERSION, PHONE_ASSOC, accountNUM);
                    facebookapp.add(fbapp);
                    }
                inputStream3.close();
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException d) {
                d.printStackTrace();
            }

    try {
        // establish connection to database
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle-lab.cs.univie.ac.at:1521:lab";
        String user = "a01547605";
        String pass = "dbs19";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, user, pass);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql3 = "INSERT into facebookapp(PRODNUM, V_ERSION, PHONE_ASSOC, accountNUM) values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql3);

        final int batchSize = 100;
        int count = 0;
        for(FBapp d: facebookapp) {
            ps.setInt(1, d.getPRODNUM());
            ps.setDouble(2, d.getV_ERSION());
            ps.setString(3, d.getPHONE_ASSOC());
            ps.setInt(4, d.getaccountNUM());
            ps.addBatch();

            if(++ count% batchSize == 0) {
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
        }
          ps.close();

      }   

          catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
          }
```

My CSV file looks as follows, this is the first row of 100

```
1   1.00    Iphone  100
```

also when I print out what is being read out of my CSV file before it cuts out this is what it looks like

```
1;1.00;Iphone
```

Comment: The last line that you show ("1;1.00;Iphone") has only 3 values ("1", "1.00", "Iphone"), but you are trying to read to 4th value that does not exist on this line!

Comment: it does in the CSV file, there is a fourth line "accountNUM" I clearly defined this in my code as well, I dont understand why it is not reading in the fourth column. Ive tried to see if there is something to correct in the csv file but everything looks totally fine

Comment: Well, the first line that you show ("1   1.00    Iphone  100") has four columns, the last line ("1;1.00;Iphone") has only three columns. It seems that one of the lines in your CSV is missing a column.

Comment: Ive opened it up with in my notepad just to see what it looks like there and here it is  1;1.00;Iphone ;100 looks totally normal...

Comment: problem resolved, it didnt like the space after Iphone and ;

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(data3);` is what's printing "1;1.00;Iphone" which should be the content of your CSV file. There's only three values on this line so since you hard-coded your program to expect a fourth value at `int accountNUM = Integer.parseInt(values3[3]);` it will fail here.

You also print data3 twice. Try printing out the contents of your array values3 in the second statement to catch code errors.